# How do I add a new object an unlimited number of times at runtime?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, runtime

Say I have a label on the screen, and a button. When the user presses the button, it makes a new label underneath the one already there, and it can do this an unlimited number of times.

I don't need the code for making a new position. I'm just wondering how I would add a new label? Can I do the same with a bunch of variables related to it too, like say create a few NSStrings?

Comment: not xcode-related. check for the usage of the tag [xcode]: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/xcode/info

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have to do is to create an UILabel view and add it to the current view as a subview programmatically.

```
 NSMutableArray *labelArray; /* assumes it has your other labels */
 UILabel *newLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(/* your frame to locate the label */)];
 newLabel.text = @"whatever";
 [self.view insertSubview:newLabel below:[labelArray lastObject]];
 [labelArray addObject:newLabel];
 [newLabel release];
```

Comment: What i had in mind was more a way that was similar to visual basic, where I'd refer to it like.. theLabel(1).text or theLabel(142).text. Can i do it like that?

Comment: Yes you can use [(UILabel)[labelArray objectAtIndex:142] text] (if there is such a object, otherwise you'd get a index out of bounds runtime error).

Comment: `[(UILabel *)[labelArray objectAtIndex:142] text]`

Answer (score 0):

```
UILabel *newLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
newLabel.text = @"Some text";
[self.view insertSubview:newLabel belowSubview:originalLabel];
```